# notify_one() in c++ thread waking up more than one thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, conditional-statements

Hello I have the following code:

```
// condition_variable example
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void print_id (int id) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  while (!ready) cv.wait(lock);
  // ...
  std::cout << "thread " << id << std::endl;
}

void go() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  ready = true;
  cv.notify_one();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread threads[10];
  // spawn 10 threads:
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(print_id,i);

  std::cout << "10 threads ready to race..." << std::endl;
  go();                       // go!

  for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
  std::cout << "Finished!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
10 threads ready to race...
thread 9
thread 0
```

My expectation is that by calling notify_one(), only one thread will be notified and I will reach a deadlock. But in this case, two threads were notified before reching deadlock. What am I missing here? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be that not all threads are started when you call `go()`. Then this might happen:

1. Nine threads are running and waiting for a condition variable.
2. You call `go()` which sets `ready` to `true` and notifies thread zero.
3. Tenth thread is started, it sees `ready` is `true` and does not wait for the condition variable.

Comment: Exactly. This is made even more probable if you remove the call to cout before go(), doing that, I can reproduce 2 threads printing.

Answer (score 3):

You should not count on the amount of notified threads. `notify_one` wakes up "at least one, if waiting threads exist".

The C++ standard allows [spurious wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Spurious_wakeup), which means a thread woken up without a notification.

Instead, check the variable you protect in the mutex. You may consider adding a counter if you want the exact-counted notification behavior.

Comment: Maybe note that `wait` takes a predicate as a second parameter that is used for detecting spurious wakeups.

Comment: @Simple it's identical to the while(cond) loop. The OP's condition is abused resulting unwanted behavior.

Comment: @Tatsuyuki Ishi, Please tell me where did you get the phrase - "at least one, if waiting threads exist". I can't find any mention of this anywhere. For example, it is not said here -https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one. It says there - "notify_one unblocks one of the waiting threads.". There is no - "at least one".